# How to execute an script from another path

Tags: java, shellexecute

I want to execute `myscript.sh` from a java project.
The call I want to do is something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./myscript.sh "+param1+" "+param2);
```

The problem is that this script.sh is not in the same path, so I tryed to do:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("src/main/resources/./myscript.sh "+param1+" "+param2);
```

But the script is not executed anymore. I guess the problem is in the way I put the path, because I have checked and the script works perfectly if it is in the same path.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you see filenotfoundexception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead. In [the documentation for Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29) you can even read the following:

> *ProcessBuilder.start() is now the preferred way to start a process with a modified environment.*

As an example shows in the documentation, you can use `pb.directory(File f)` to set the working directory:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
// ...
pb.directory("myDir");
Process p = pb.start();
```